# How to call jQuery event using HtmlElement.InvokeMember

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am trying to call the jQuery `KeyDown` of textbox event by using C# `htmlelement.InvokeMember` function but it's not working as expected.

When I try to run the same C# function on Javascript `onkeydown` event it works fine.

Here is my code

Html markup:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#txt1").keydown(function(t) {

alert("Hello BLACKswastik");

})
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt1" />

<input onkeydown="alert('Hi BLACKswastik')" type="text" id="number" name="number" value=""/>

</body>
</html>
```

C# Code :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //JQUERY EVENT TEXTBOX not working
    HtmlElement htte = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txt1");
    htte.InnerText = "BLACKSWASTIK";
    htte.InvokeMember("OnKeyDown",13);

    //JAVASCRIPT EVENT TEXTBOX working fine
    HtmlElement htte = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("number");
    htte.InnerText = "BLACKSWASTIK";
    htte.InvokeMember("OnKeyDown",13);
}
```

Is that mean we can not call the jQuery event by using `Invokemember` function of C# or is there any error in my code? Please help me..

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: what is webBrowser1 ? Is it hosted in Windows Form or WPF application?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery "on" function to bind events dynamically.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txt1").on("keydown",function(t) {
  alert("Hello");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
<input onkeydown="$(this).trigger('keydown');" type="text" id="txt1" />
```